# How do I align variable descriptions in a list of variables when variables are different sizes?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

I am writing a list of variables using `\begin{description}` and `enumitem`. The variables are different sizes, and therefore `\hspace` or other spacing methods do not produce an even right alignment for the descriptions following each variable, which is what I want. Again, the goal is to have the text describing each variable begin at a set point from the page edge so it is right aligned. Here is my text:

```
\begin{description}[labelindent=20pt]

\item[$Q$] volumetric flow rate

\item[$c$] molar concentration

\item[$r$] rate of generation of a species

\item[$V$] volume

\item[$CV$] control volume

\end{description}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify an additional `align`ment as well as the `widest` element to obtain an appropriate layout if you wish to retain the use of `description`:

```
\begin{description}[...,align=right,widest=$CV$]
  \item[.] ...
  %...
\end{description}
```

It's also just simpler to use a natural right-alignment provided by `itemize`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[labelindent=20pt]
  \item[$Q$] volumetric flow rate
  \item[$c$] molar concentration
  \item[$r$] rate of generation of a species
  \item[$V$] volume
  \item[$CV$] control volume
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is sensible, but you can also use `labelwidth`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[10][1-4]
\begin{description}[labelwidth=20pt,align=left]
  \item[$Q$] volumetric flow rate
  \item[$c$] molar concentration
  \item[$r$] rate of generation of a species
  \item[$V$] volume
  \item[$CV$] control volume
\end{description}
\lipsum[20][1-4]
\begin{description}[labelindent=10pt,labelwidth=20pt,align=left]
  \item[$Q$] volumetric flow rate
  \item[$c$] molar concentration
  \item[$r$] rate of generation of a species
  \item[$V$] volume
  \item[$CV$] control volume
\end{description}
\lipsum[30][1-4]

\end{document}
```

It's better to define a suitable environment, though:

```
\newenvironment{vardesc}[1][20pt]
 {\begin{description}[labelwidth=#1,labelindent=10pt,align=left]}
 {\end{description}}
```

so you can change the parameters once and for all such descriptions in the document. You can call it

```
\begin{vardesc}
```

or

```
\begin{vardesc}[30pt]
```

The latter for cases where you need to override the default width.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation of how to create an environment for future variable lists - this will definitely expedite the process.